# Reading from NetworkStream corrupts the buffer

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous, system.reactive

When reading data from NetworkStream with ReadUntilClosedObservable1, the returned data is corrupted like some blocks of read data overlap.

However, when I read the data with ReadUntilClosedObservable2 the data arrives without problems.

I want to use the ReadUntilClosedObservable1 because repeatedly reading from stream in ReadUntilClosedObservable2 is burning the CPU.

How can I get the messages in sync order?

**UPDATE:**

```
return Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, interval, TaskPoolScheduler.Default)
                    .SelectMany(_ => readToEnd)
                    .Where(dataChunk => dataChunk.Length > 0);
```

I just noticed that `readToEnd` to is fired again and again before it finishes the previous job. Doesn't it need to be synchronized? If `Observable.Timer` is the problem how can I achieve the same effect without it, reading in intervals but starting without waiting?

```
public static IObservable<int> ReadObservable(this Stream stream, byte[] buffer
                                              ,int offset, int count)
{
    return stream.ReadAsync(buffer, offset, count)
                    .ToObservable();
}

public static IObservable<byte[]> ReadObservable(this Stream stream,
                                                 int bufferSize)
{
    var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    return stream.ReadObservable(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
                    .Select(cbRead =>
                                {
                                    if (cbRead == 0)
                                    {
                                        return new byte[0];
                                    }

                                    if (cbRead == buffer.Length)
                                    {
                                        return buffer;
                                    }

                                    var dataChunk = new byte[cbRead];

                                    Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, dataChunk,
                                                     0, cbRead);

                                    return dataChunk;
                                });
}

public static IObservable<byte[]> ReadUntilClosedObservable1(this NetworkStream
                                     stream, int bufferSize, TimeSpan interval)
{
    var readToEnd = Observable.Defer(() => stream.ReadObservable(bufferSize))
                                .DoWhile(() => stream.DataAvailable)
                                .ToList()
                                .Select(dataChunks =>
                                    {
                                        var buffer = new List<byte>();

                                        foreach (var dataChunk in dataChunks)
                                        {
                                            buffer.AddRange(dataChunk);
                                        }

                                        return buffer.ToArray();
                                    });

    return Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, interval, TaskPoolScheduler.Default)
                        .SelectMany(_ => readToEnd)
                        .Where(dataChunk => dataChunk.Length > 0);
}

public static IObservable<byte[]> ReadUntilClosedObservable2(this Stream stream
                                                             ,int bufferSize)
{
    return Observable.Defer(() => stream.ReadObservable(bufferSize))
                        .Repeat()
                        .Where(dataChunk => dataChunk.Length > 0);
}
```

Comment: I suspect that this is the problem `Buffer.BlockCopy` I would almost bet that when you run the code without the Buffer.BlockCopy that the Observable2 one runs with half the memory.`BlockCopy doesn't have managed .NET implementation. Internally, it invokes external win api.`

Comment: @DJKRAZE: The problem is not with BlockCopy. I changed the copy part to: return buffer.Take(cbRead).ToArray(); But the problem is still there.

Comment: Also done for a FileStream on IntroToRx.com
http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/15_SchedulingAndThreading.html#CreatingYourOwnIterator

Answer (score 0):

Oh, no, no...don't do it like that...

Async + Rx is one of the more...*non-intuitive* setups to get working, but it is quite a bit simpler than what you're attempting. The key bits are three different Rx operators:

- `FromAsyncPattern`: generates a "`IObservable` Factory" from an async call signature
- `Observable.Defer`: allows you to use above `IObservable` factory to generate observables per subscriber
- `Observable.While`: allows you to "Reinvoke until I say when" on an `IObservable`

(EDIT: altered to use a `NetworkStream` example)

(doubleEDIT: altered based on comments)

Try this - unless I miss my guess, it's more or less what you're trying for:

```
void Main()
{    
    // We'll feed this to listener
    var message = "Yo mamma said you like messages like this";

    var listenerTask = Task
        .Factory
        .StartNew(() => 
            {
                var bufferSize = 1024;
                var localhost = new IPAddress(new byte[]{127,0,0,1});
                var listener = new TcpListener(localhost, 11201);
                listener.Start();
                var incomingClient = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                var clientStream = incomingClient.GetStream();
                // our buffered reader
                var observer = clientStream.ReadObservable(bufferSize);
                var compareBuffer = observer
                    // Take while we're getting data and the client
                    // is still connected
                    .TakeWhile(returnBuffer => returnBuffer.Length > 0 && 
                        incomingClient.Connected)
                    // In between read blocks, respond back to the client
                    // No need for fanciness here, just normal async writeback
                    .Do(returnBuffer => clientStream.BeginWrite(
                             returnBuffer, 
                             0, 
                             returnBuffer.Length, 
                             ar => clientStream.EndWrite(ar), 
                             null))
                    .ToEnumerable()
                    .SelectMany (returnBuffer => returnBuffer)
                    .ToArray();
                listener.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine(
                     "Listener thinks it was told... {0}", 
                     Encoding.ASCII.GetString(compareBuffer));
            });

    var clientTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(
        () => 
        {
            var client = new TcpClient();
            client.Connect("localhost", 11201);
            var random = new Random();
            var outStream = client.GetStream();
            var bytesToSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
            foreach(byte toSend in bytesToSend)
            {
                // send a character over
                outStream.WriteByte(toSend);

                // Listener should parrot us...
                int goOn = outStream.ReadByte();
                if(goOn != toSend)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(
                        "Huh. Listener echoed wrong. I said: {0}, they said {1}", 
                         toSend, 
                         goOn);
                    break;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("I said: {0}, they said {1}", toSend, goOn);

                // Take a little nap (simulate latency, etc)
                Thread.Sleep(random.Next(200));
            }
            client.Close();
        });

    Task.WaitAll(listenerTask, clientTask);
}


public static class Ext
{        
    public static IObservable<byte[]> ReadObservable(this Stream stream, int bufferSize)
    {        
        // to hold read data
        var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        // Step 1: async signature => observable factory
        var asyncRead = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<byte[], int, int, int>(
            stream.BeginRead, 
            stream.EndRead);
        return Observable.While(
            // while there is data to be read
            () => stream.CanRead, 
            // iteratively invoke the observable factory, which will
            // "recreate" it such that it will start from the current
            // stream position - hence "0" for offset
            Observable.Defer(() => asyncRead(buffer, 0, bufferSize))
                .Select(readBytes => buffer.Take(readBytes).ToArray()));
    }
}
```

Comment: When I change the code to: `return readToEnd.Repeat()
                            .Where(dataChunk => dataChunk.Length > 0);` from `return Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, interval, TaskPoolScheduler.Default)
                             .SelectMany(_ => readToEnd)
                             .Where(dataChunk => dataChunk.Length > 0);` It works perfect but a little heavy on CPU.

Comment: @SametSorgut Nah, in that case you just need to alter your TakeWhile accordingly...when I get a moment, I'll augment this to work with a tcp  client/listener, is that what you're trying to adapt?

Comment: Yes TcpClient. Connecting, Reading the data repeatedly, responding to read messages and when done closing the connection. All in RX.

Comment: @SametSorgut Ah, I see...the response in between would be tricky with this example - one sec, I'll alter accordingly.

Comment: @JerKimball Rxx seems to do it very differently. Can anyone elaborate? https://github.com/RxDave/Rxx/blob/master/Main/Source/Rxx.Bindings-Net451/System/IO/StreamExtensions.cs

Comment: There's a gotcha with this implementation. Different subscribers will get different shares of the stream data! One has to append a `.Publish().Connect()` to ensure all subscribers get all data.